# Prevent image being deleted from profile

Tags: php, sql

I have an issue with my site I am putting together.

I understand what the problem is but am not sure how to fix it.

What I have is a profile site and I am adding a photo to the site.

Now when you go into edit the profile, if you do not provide an image for the profile then the $FILE[] array is empty and hence it populates the db with blank values essentially deleting my photo.

I want to do something like:

```
if $uploadfile = " " DO NOT WRITE ANYTHING TO THE DB.
```

Just so you know, $uploadfile = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];

My code looks like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'upload')
{
  $uploadfile = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
  $uploadname = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
  $uploadtype = $_FILES['upload']['type'];
  $uploaddata = file_get_contents($uploadfile);
}
```

AND THE EDIT CODE LOOKS LIKE THIS

```
    // EDIT A PLAYER PROFILE

    if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Edit' )
    {
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';
        try
        {
            // $sql = 'SELECT id, name, age, position, height, weight, satscore, gpa FROM player WHERE id = :id';
            $sql = 'SELECT player.id, player.name AS name, age, position, height, weight, previousclubs.id AS previousclubsid, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct previousclubs.name) previousclubs, 
                satscore, gpa, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct link) link, email, filename, mimetype, filedata
                FROM player INNER JOIN playerpreviousclubs
                    ON player.id = playerid
                INNER JOIN previousclubs
                    ON previousclubid = previousclubs.id
                INNER JOIN links
                    ON links.playerid = player.id
                WHERE player.id = :id';
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
            $s->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $error = 'Error fetching profile details.' . $e->getMessage();
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }

        $row = $s->fetch();
        $pageTitle = 'Edit Profile';
        $action = 'editform';
        $name = $row['name'];
        $age = $row['age']; 
        $position = $row['position'];
        $height = $row['height'];
        $weight = $row['weight'];
        $satscore = $row['satscore'];
        $gpa = $row['gpa'];
        $previousclubs = $row['previousclubs'];
        $previousclubsid = $row['previousclubsid'];
        $link = $row['link'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $filename = $row['filename'];
        $mimetype = $row['mimetype'];
        $filedata = $row['filedata'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        $button = 'Update Profile';

        include 'addplayerprofile.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    if (isset($_GET['editform']))
    {
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/db.inc.php';

        // UPDATE MAIN PLAYER PROFILE DETAILS
        try
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE player SET
                name = :name,
                age = :age,
                position = :position,
                height = :height,
                weight = :weight,
                satscore = :satscore,
                gpa = :gpa,
                email = :email,
                    filename = :filename,
                    mimetype = :mimetype,
                    filedata = :filedata
                WHERE id = :id";
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
            $s->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
            $s->bindValue(':age', $_POST['age']);
            $s->bindValue(':position', $_POST['position']);
            $s->bindValue(':height', $_POST['height']);
            $s->bindValue(':weight', $_POST['weight']);
            $s->bindValue(':satscore', $_POST['satscore']);
            $s->bindValue(':gpa', $_POST['gpa']);
            $s->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
                    $s->bindValue(':filename',  $uploadname);
                    $s->bindValue(':mimetype',   $uploadtype);
                    $s->bindValue(':filedata',   $uploaddata);
            $s->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $error = 'Error editing player profile main details.' . $e->getMessage();
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }

        // UPDATE PREVIOUS CLUBS
        try
        {
            $sql = 'UPDATE previousclubs SET
                name = :previousclubs
                WHERE id = :previousclubsid';
            $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $s->bindValue(':previousclubs', $_POST['previousclubs']);
            $s->bindValue(':previousclubsid', $_POST['previousclubsid']);
            $s->execute();
        }
        catch (PDOException $e)
        {
            $error = 'Error editing player previous clubs.' . $e->getMessage();
            include 'error.html.php';
            exit();
        }   

header('Location: .');
exit();
}
```

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a simple `if` statement there:

```
try
    {
        $photo_string = (isset($uploadfile)) ? ",
                filename = :filename,
                mimetype = :mimetype,
                filedata = :filedata" : null;

        $sql = "UPDATE player SET
            name = :name,
            age = :age,
            position = :position,
            height = :height,
            weight = :weight,
            satscore = :satscore,
            gpa = :gpa,
            email = :email
            WHERE id = :id $photo_string";
        $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
        $s->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name']);
        $s->bindValue(':age', $_POST['age']);
        $s->bindValue(':position', $_POST['position']);
        $s->bindValue(':height', $_POST['height']);
        $s->bindValue(':weight', $_POST['weight']);
        $s->bindValue(':satscore', $_POST['satscore']);
        $s->bindValue(':gpa', $_POST['gpa']);
        $s->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
        if (isset($uploadfile)) {
                $s->bindValue(':filename',  $uploadname);
                $s->bindValue(':mimetype',   $uploadtype);
                $s->bindValue(':filedata',   $uploaddata);
        }
        $s->execute();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your reply.  Is that closing } above the $sql correct?  It's not working for me as I'm not closing or opening a bracket somewhere.  Thanks.

Comment: No, sorry. It's a mistake. I'll modify it for you.

Comment: Thanks but I am getting some errors.  They are as follows Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\connect\admin\index.php on line 26
Error editing player profile main details.SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' filename = '', mimetype = '', ' at line 10

Comment: Line 26 = $uploaddata = file_get_contents($uploadfile);

Comment: Read the error message. It means that `$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']` is empty. You need to figure out why and fix that first.

Comment: Hi Mike, until I figure out why that array is empty, I will not know if the solution has worked.  I believe the reason it is empty is because I am not selecting an image and therefore there will be nothing in the $FILE array.  However, how I stop this flagging up as a warning I do not know?  Can I put a dummy value in there?  Is that allowed?  Rest assured I will definitely accept your answer once I work this out.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Arr I think I see what is going on.  $uploaddata is getting set to the contents of $uploadfile and because there has been no file chosen, both $uploadfile and $uploaddate are empty.  Getting there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but if you just want to check that a file has been uploaded, you can replace the first line by:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'upload' && isset($_FILES['upload']))
```

or if you want to execute you code normally apart from the DB update:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'upload') {
    // Some code
    if (isset($_FILES['upload'])) {
        // Database Update
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks for your reply.  That isn't working but it is along the lines of what I am trying to do so I will play with it and see if I can get it working.  Thanks for your time and help.